# Proof of Sylvester's Theorem

Tags: number-theory

> If $p$ and $q$ are relative primes, prove that the number of integers inferior to $pq$ which cannot be resolved into parts (zeroes admissible), nonnegative multiples of $p$ and $q$, is $$\dfrac{1}{2}(p-1)(q-1).$$
>   (*Sylvester*)

A a proof given of this is given below, but I don't understand how it is valid. How when we plug in $x=1$ with four deducted we get twice the number of integers less than $pq$? According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794392/numbers-of-the-form-paqb-n/1794409#1794409) question I asked it is possible that some of the terms $pa+pq$ are the same and also why are we adding the coefficients  if we just want to know the number of multiples?

**Book's solution:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The book is saying the following: if $f(x):=\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^q\,x^{pi}\right)\,\left(\sum\limits_{j=0}^p\,x^{qj}\right)$, then $f(x)$ is self-reciprocal (namely, $x^{2pq}\,f\left(\frac1x\right)=f(x)$) and given by $$f(x)=1+\left(\sum_{r \in S}\,x^r\right)+2x^{pq}+\left(\sum_{r\in S}\,x^{2pq-r}\right)+x^{2pq}\,,$$
where $S$ is the set of positive integers less than $pq$ expressible as $mp+nq$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$.  Therefore, $(p+1)(q+1)=f(1)=1+|S|+2+|S|+1$, or $|S|=\frac{(p+1)(q+1)}{2}-2$.  Hence, $\{1,2,\ldots,pq-1\}\setminus S$ has $(pq-1)-\left(\frac{(p+1)(q+1)}{2}-2\right)=\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2}$ elements.

Comment: Is the $x^1$ in the solution a typo?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.